# Split css grid 2 columns into 3 for specific row

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a 2 column layout and wish to split one row to a 3 column layout is that possible without specifying the 3 column layout initially?

Example

all 7s should be split to 3 parts in that row (see code output)

1 to 1.5 obviously doesn't work.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.custom {
  grid-column: 1/1.5
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item custom">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item custom">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item custom">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what the issue of having 6 columns that you can easily split to 3 + 3 or 2+2+2 ?

Comment: I've designed everything with 2 columns and do not want to redesign it, just need that one row to stick out of the grid layout. Can it be done? A grid of 6 columns seems like an overkill

Comment: you can understand now why most of the frameworks uses 12 columns layout and this not overkill at all. This is what you should be doing here. You can probably hack 3 columns but what if you need later 4 columns?  better correct the design early and avoid hacks

Comment: I was thinking of hacking 2 columns, by spanning the one column to 2 taking the whole row and then an inner div with display flex on it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *hack* that should be used with caution (or not used at all)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.custom {
  width: 66.66%
}

.custom+.custom {
  margin-left: -33.33%;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row:3;
}

.custom+.custom+.custom {
  margin-left: 33.33%;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row:3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item custom">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item custom">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item custom">7</div>
</div>
```

And the logical solution is to move to 6 columns:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  grid-column:span 3;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.custom {
 grid-column:span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item custom">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item custom">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item custom">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was on something similar albeit you don't need a  grid-row:3; on the last class. Anyways +1 and 15

Comment: @EugenSunic you don't need the grid-row and grid-column ;) but for the demo purpose I kept them to clearly see that I am defining the same position for both of them.